# What is the fastest way to move data from one volume to another with MapR?

Tags: hadoop, mapr, distcp

I want to move data from one volume to another. The folders and file sizes vary. Files can be up to 100 GB, but we can have also a lot of small files. If there is data in the destination volume at that particular folder, it can be overwritten.

So far, I tried (Code has been simplified for demonstration purposes)

```
   (1)for root, directories, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            mv -v <src> <dest>

   (2)hadoop distcp -overwrite -m100 <src> <dest>
```

Less than 10 GB, the mv option is faster. At 10 GB both options take approx 2 minutes transfer time.

Comment: I didn't think distcp could address local volumes

Comment: @cricket_007: distcp works. I took over a code in which all data is copied with it.

Comment: What I meant was its not meant to be used for `file://` sources and destinations, even though it'll spin up mapreduces to copy faster than serially running `mv`

Comment: Yes, that is true. It was not specifically designed for moving data from one to another volume. But thats why I am asking. I applied to methods and i assume there are more options. My web research was not conclusive.

Comment: Again, distcp runs within YARN, as MapReduce. So, any local filesystem targets will be random machines in the cluster. I don't think your question has anything to do with MapR if it's only local files https://superuser.com/questions/488333/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-move-a-million-images-from-one-directory-to-another

Comment: Maybe there was one point not clear: 
src data is one MapR volume and the data needs to be moved to another MapR volume.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know MapR terminology. Volumes/partitions only exist on a local filesystem in my mind